# CPU frequency not changing in Ubuntu 13.10 Thinkpad T440

Tags: 13.10, thinkpad, turbo-boost

I'm using a Thinkpad T440 with Ubuntu 13.10, and Turboboost doesn't seem to be working. The processors almost always remain at the minimum, 0.8Ghz.

Here is the output of turbostat:

```
cor CPU    %c0  GHz  TSC SMI    %c1    %c3    %c6    %c7 CTMP PTMP   %pc2   %pc3   %pc6   %pc7   %pc8   %pc9  %pc10  Pkg_W  Cor_W GFX_W
         99.96 0.80 2.49   0   0.04   0.00   0.00   0.00   49   50   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   4.52   1.68  0.02
  0   0  99.99 0.80 2.49   0   0.01   0.00   0.00   0.00   49   50   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   4.52   1.68  0.02
  0   1  99.99 0.80 2.49   0   0.01
  1   2  99.87 0.80 2.49   0   0.13   0.00   0.00   0.00   47
  1   3  99.99 0.80 2.49   0   0.01
```

During this, I'm running 4 busy loops so htop reports every core to be running at 100%.

My processor: Intel® Core™ i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz × 4

Anyone have any guesses why the cpu frequency doesn't update?

Comment: There's a slightly bigger issue: your processor frequency isn't changing at all. Even without turboboost, you should be able to go up to 1.9 Ghz. With turboboost, you could go up to 2.9 Ghz.

Comment: Oh right. I was thinking turboboost was what controlled all changing of the CPU frequency. I've updated the question, thanks.

Comment: Is the CPU hogging program running in the idle or maximum nice priority class?

Answer (score 1):

You can also monitor frequency changes using my GUI , and beside that, low, high & Turbo ratios.

You will be surprise that standard `/proc/cpuinfo` is not accurate because the Base Clock is not updated. Check one of the Widgets I named **System Information**.

In the other Widget named Cores, click Task to see in real time which processes are hogging your  CPUs.

You can get source code and instructions at http://code.google.com/p/xfreq/

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what was causing the problem, but I just decided to update to Ubuntu 14.04 (Beta 1) and the CPU seems to be scaling properly now.